# How to do model evaluation with train, validation, test?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, classification, cross-validation

Generally if one dataset is given we use

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
y_pred = lr.predict(X_test)
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred))
print(accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred))
```

If we are doing validation on the training dataset

```
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
```

If both Train and Test datasets are given in separate datasets, where do I use Test dataset in the code?

Comment: I suggest you to send this question to https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What else were you given?  If you were also given the train dataset, then you would simply skip the line where you do `train_test_split` and then proceed with the following steps you outline.

Comment: `X_train` datasets is used to fit the model. Usually part of `X_train` datasets that is not used for fitting - `X_val` dataset - is used to evaluate the model (eg if model has overfitting/underfitting) and based on this evaluation you can fix your model. So `X_val` dataset is used for model correction. And then after model correction if it was needed we consider that model fitting is finished and we make a prediction using complitely new dataset for our model - `X_test`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I will split the available data 2 times like this:

[image]

```
#first split: 80% (green+blue) and 20% (orange)
X_model, X_test, y_model, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

#second split: 75% (green) and 25% (orange)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_model, y_model, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)
```

Note the the first split is 80:20 ratio, and the second split is 75:25 ratio, in order to get the 60:20:20 ratio in the overall dataset. And if you're already given separate dataset for model train/val and model test, you can skip the first split.

After this you can proceed to train and evaluate the model (using `_train` and `_val`):

```
lr = some_model()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = lr.predict(X_val)
print(confusion_matrix(y_val, y_pred))
print(accuracy_score(y_val, y_pred))    #accuracy score (TRAIN)
print(classification_report(y_val, y_pred))
```

This is repeated using various models, and in model tuning, until you can find the best performing model and hyperparameters. It is highly recommended to do [cross validation](https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/) here to identify a better and more robust model.

[image]

After the winning model is found, do a test on the holdout data (using `_test`):

```
y_pred = lr.predict(X_test)
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))    #accuracy score (TEST)
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

Now you can compare the 2 accuracy scores (TRAIN and TEST) to see if model is overfitting or underfitting.